# How to generalise a custom plotting function to plot multiple different things

Tags: python, function, class, plot

I have built a model class where I can fit various models, a simple RNN, an LSTM RNN with the goal of adding more models. The history is stored in `self.<model>_history`. I would like to be able to plot the training and validation accuracy:

`self.<model>_history.history['accuracy']` and `self.<model>_history.history['val_accuracy']`

or training and validation loss:

`self.<model>_history.history['loss']` and `self.<model>_history.history['val_loss']`

for each model using just one plotting function. Please see my workaround below, which does work but it doesn't look nice. Item could be either 'loss' or 'accuracy'

```html
  def plot_model(self, model, item='accuracy'):
    if model == 'lstm':
      plt.plot(self.lstm_history.history[f'{item}'])
      plt.plot(self.lstm_history.history[f'val_{item}'])
      plt.legend([f'Training {item.title()}', f'Validation {item}'])
      plt.xlabel('Epoch')
      plt.ylabel(f'{item}')
      plt.show()
    if model == 'rnn':
      plt.plot(self.rnn_history.history[f'{item}'])
      plt.plot(self.rnn_history.history[f'val_{item}'])
      plt.legend([f'Training {item.title()}', f'Validation {item}'])
      plt.xlabel('Epoch')
      plt.ylabel(f'{item}')
      plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
def plot_model(self, model, item='accuracy'):
    _model = getattr(self, '%s_history' % model)
    plt.plot(_model.history[f'{item}'])
    plt.plot(_model.history[f'val_{item}'])
    plt.legend([f'Training {item.title()}', f'Validation {item}'])
    plt.xlabel('Epoch')
    plt.ylabel(f'{item}')
    plt.show()
```

gettattr should help you to obtain the object `<model>_history` you need